# Custom field when adding new site to multisite networked WordPress

Tags: custom-field, multisite, network-admin

I have a multisite setup in WordPress. Is there a way for me to implement a custom field when I create a new site in Admin > Sites > Add New. My current options are Site Address, Site Title, Admin Email. I'd like to add another field that I could fill in to be associated with these new sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, bad news.

If you look in the code-base of WP 3.9 for the responsible PHP file (which is [site-new.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-admin/network/site-new.php)) you'll unfortunately see that this is all hardcoded, like a lot of stuff in wp-admin, which IMHO totally sucks. :-(

The only thing you can do is to build your own page for site creation and make it replace the default wordpress one.

---

***To give you a start on this:***

The easiest way to do this is to use [add_menu_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) to define your own custom admin menu page.

```
add_menu_page( 'Add site', 'Add site', 'manage_options', 'cusom-new-site-page', function() {
        // your custom code for this page ...
});
```

The function to create a new site is [wpmu_create_blog()](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/wpmu_create_blog), but you can also look into the existing file for that logic.

After this you could use [add_rewrite_rule()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) to add a rewrite from the existing page to your custom one. Your rewrite rule could look like this one:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/wp-admin/network/site-new.php $1/wp-admin/admin.php?page=cusom-new-site-page [L]
```

Comment: Ahh, I was hoping it was going to be a bit less complex. Thanks for looking into this though.